# TFS TLS 1.1/1.2

Tags: ssl, tfs

We are currently using TFS 2015.3 on Windows server 2012 R2. After using NARTAC to specify using TLS1.1/1.2 and disable TLS1.0, our build tier server cannot connect to application tier server.

Does any have the same issue and got it fixed? Thank you

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Seems it's not supported for TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.

Ensure that your installation of TFS, the underlying .NET version(s), and Windows Server all support TLS 1.2 endpoints.

.NET Framework version(s) used by TFS must support TLS 1.2. Some .NET Framework versions may require additional registry settings for "`SchUseStrongCrypto`" as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityAdvisories/2015/2960358#Suggested%20Actions).

Whatever, you can have a try with the solution mentioned below:

> By default .Net has a setting called “useStrongCrypto” that allows the
>   client PC to use TLS 1.1 and higher.
>
> To enable secure your local client PC to use TLS 1.1 and higher (or as
>   Microsoft terms is “strong crypto”) you need to edit the following
>   registry entries:
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SchUseStrongCrypto = 00000001 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SchUseStrongCrypto= 00000001`
>
> Or you could simply cut and paste the following into a .reg file and run it (only do this if you know what you’re doing).
>
> `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
>     "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001`
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
>     "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001`
>
> ***Source here : [Getting WebDeploy working after disabling insecure Ciphers like SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2016/02/28/pci-compliant-web-deploy-getting-webdeploy-working-after-disabling-insecure-ciphers-like-ssl-30-and-tls-10)***

Also this article for your reference: [Misbehaving HTTPS Servers impair TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/24/misbehaving-https-servers-impair-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/)

Comment: It is not working on our server. I am not sure if the TFS 2015.3 supports TLS 1.2. Our Servers are Windows server 2012 R2 which has no problem with TLS 1.2. We have .net framework 4.6.1 as the highest version of .net framework and some lower version, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5.

We use IISCrypto to specify TLS1.2 and TFS URL can be visited, but we lost the build function. It seems the connection between application tier servers and build tier servers is lost.

Comment: This registry entry is not working.


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001

Comment: This registry entry is not working either.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SchUseStrongCrypto = 00000001 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SchUseStrongCrypto= 00000001

Comment: @robin Have you tried to add the both of the entries? note that add the entries under `.NETFramework\v4.0.30319`

Comment: for the entries under .NETFramework\v4.0.30319, I have tried HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft and add dword SchUse‌​StrongCrypto= 00000001, but they are not working

Comment: Not working also for me :( Any other check to do? I'm with Win2012R2 and TFS2017.2

Answer (score 0):

Not   \Microsoft.NETFramework\  You forgot the \ after Microsoft on the 2nd registry set

Use:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
    "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
    "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```