# TFS 2015 Update 4 The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl, tfs, tfs-2015

Randomly out of nowhere my TFS 2015 self hosted install stopped sending Slack webhooks. The error I get is

```
 An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: 
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I've tried forcing the crypto to use a certain TLS to no avail. I'm out of options as I've followed everything I can find on google with no luck.

Comment: It's probable that TFS 2015 used TLS 1.1 and Slack dropped support for it. You're years overdue for a TFS upgrade; past a certain point you have to expect that integrations are going to break. Googling TFS and TLS 1.1/1.2 gives a lot of options you can investigate to make it work, but I haven't tried any of them and can't give a definitive answer on whether they work or not. Your safest path is to upgrade to Azure DevOps Server 2019.

Comment: I.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669541/tfs-tls-1-1-1-2

Comment: Does the issue happen randomly or always? Could you capture a fiddler trace?

Comment: I've followed pretty much every step i can find. I've done the strong crypto, etc.

Comment: @TheDizzle Does the issue happen randomly or always? Could you capture a fiddler trace?